# Php and htaccess error - "no input file specified"

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I am using Rester to make RESTful APIs from my MySQL databases.

https://github.com/moddity/Rester

Everything is working fine on localhost, but when I upload it to my GoDaddy hosting account and I try to visit the rewritten urls, I get the "no input file specified" error. My .htaccess file contains:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try, Go to Godaddy Webroot  and make an `php5 ini` file with the following Rules,

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
```

Comment: HAve a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186058/no-input-file-specified-godaddy